# Javascript Prototype Property'

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

I am following the logic within javascript regarding 'function Constructors' and 'Prototype Chains' however I am trying to resolve the importance of the prototype chain in terms of how exactly it is needed.

The function Constructor is useful for creating objects, --right?  Therefore upon creation of an object when using the 'Function Constructor' does that object not already possess the pointer to the 'global object' higher up in the chain?  ...and if so why then include this 'prototype property' at all?  or...
does the prototype property actually 'instantiate' the inheritance chain that links the functions object to the global object.

If the prototype property does not instantiate a link between local and global context of objects why include it at all?  If I omit the prototype property from a function constructor's list of properties what would change?

I just need a clear, concise reason behind the purpose of the prototype property , which at this point makes some sense but still no sense in terms of how it contributes to the inheritance chain.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just need a clear, concise reason behind the purpose of the prototype property , which at this point makes some sense but still no sense in terms of how it contributes to the inheritance chain.

Let's take this code for example:

```js
function Foo(prop) {
  this.fooProperty = prop
}

Foo.prototype.greetFoo = function() {
  console.log('hi from foo')
}

function Bar(prop1, prop2) {
  Foo.call(this, ...arguments)
  this.barProperty = prop2
}

// Replace the default Bar.prototype object with one that links to Foo.prototype
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype)
Bar.prototype.greetBar = function() {
  console.log('hi from bar')
}

const barInstance1 = new Bar('baz', 'rar')
const barInstance2 = new Bar('qum', 'yas')

barInstance1.greetFoo()
barInstance2.greetFoo()
barInstance1.greetBar()
barInstance2.greetBar()
```

The above would yield the following prototype chain:

```
Object.prototype <- Foo.prototype <- Bar.prototype <- barInstance1
                    > greetFoo()     > greetBar()     > fooProperty = 'baz'
                                                      > barProperty = 'rar'
                                                   <- barInstance2
                                                      > fooProperty = 'qum'
                                                      > barProperty = 'yas'
```

In traditional OOP, classes are "blueprints", and instances are objects created from the "flattened/merged" blueprints of the inheritance hierarchy of the instanced class. JS "inheritance" works differently from that. JS inheritance works using a hierarchy of linked, *live* objects, not blueprints.

When you access something on the instance that the instance doesn't have (like `greetFoo()` and `greetBar()`), JS will recursively look up the chain to find it. This chain could involve other prototypes, with more functions. This is how JS "code sharing" works.

In the example above,

- `barInstance1` and `barInstance2` are linked to `Bar.prototype`. Both instances now have `greetBar()`.
- `Bar.prototype` also links to `Foo.prototype`, which means the instances also get `greetFoo`.
- Lastly, `Foo.prototype` links to the built-in `Object.prototype`, making all instances have access to all native object methods like `hasOwnProperty`, `toString()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute the following line of code

```
function Dog(){
    this.constBreed = "Pug";
}
Dog.prototype.breed = "Bull";

var newDog = new Dog();

console.log(newDog);
```

The log will give you below result

```
Dog {constBreed: "Pug"}
    constBreed: "Pug"
    __proto__:
        breed: "Bull"
        constructor: ƒ Dog()
        __proto__: Object
```

Here the constructor variable "constBreed" is directly attached to "newDog" object, and the prototype property "breed" goes to **proto** chain.

So this is very useful because we can create multiple new Dog variables from Dog() function and change the breed of them all at once just by changing the protopye.breed of Dog() function itself.

And in case of constructor variable "constBreed" it just gets copied and newly initialised for every new object you create from Dog() function.

Comment: Hi, so if I were leave out any prototype property when writing a constructor function, when I created new objects under that function these objects would directly reference the constructor function and global object toString() etc but would not be sharable such as they are when the prototype property IS included, correct?...and on the other hand IF I included a prototype property than it would be possible to link other functions using the prototype keyword?

Comment: Yes perfect!! That's exactly how it happens and we can utilize it

Comment: I am having a difficult time conceptualizing the direct significance of the prototype keyword concept.  If creating a new object why not just use the new keyword and leave it at that?  Or if changing an object of a constructor function why not just change the objects title.  How does using prototype save time? ..If one needs a new method within a constructor function why not just write a new method into the constructor function?  The point of where I am getting a little confused is the sharing part.  Could you simplify the process for me?

Comment: I think one important we should notice with prototype keyword is that it may not save time but it saves a lot of **memory** because when we use "new" everything inside constructor will get copied and new memory resource will get allocated for them, but everything present in the prototype will just get referenced head and no new memory resource is utilized right.

Also as we know every basic js base function like map, filter, toString, etc are actually a result of this "prototype" and saves  a lot of memory since they are made accessible in all variables

Comment: Hi thanks for all your help.  I gave the upvote to the first answer because the distinction between other OOP languages and javascript filled in some gaps in my knowledge that helped me make better sense of this 'prototype' expression.  Your help HugeBelieve also helped me slightly expand my knowledge too, so thank you.  If I could have I would have split the vote.